# Liferay 6.1 how to remove header section for embedded portlet

Tags: liferay

I am working on Liferay 6.1 and I want to remove portlet header section completely for one of the portlet( This should not be visible for admin even)

Header section is edit,minimize,maximize,delete and title bar.

I have tried removing border but in vain. Also tried additional style sheet options

PortletId is correct as I am able to change other styles

```
p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_.portlet-borderless-bar {
display:none;
}

p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_.portlet-topper {
display: none;
}

p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_.portlet-title {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: i guess p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_ .portlet-title try with this(space before ".portlet-title")

Comment: I tried it is not working.                                                                                                                     #p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_. portlet-title {
 display: none;
}

Comment: it seems that you put "space" after "." put "space" before "." and keep ".portlet-title" together. Paste below code directly and see what happens

#p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_ .portlet-title {
display: none;
}

Comment: It worked but for me I have to keep space before style 
".portlet-borderless-bar". Wondering why space should create any problem here.

Comment: because ".portlet-borderless-bar" is a css class. Is your problem resloved?

Comment: Yes it is resolved. Thanks for your valuable help. Can you please redirect me some where so I can understand this space problem. I am new to CSS as well so struggling with  both Liferay and CSS.

Comment: yes. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: I am converting my comments to answer so that it will be helpfull to some one

Comment: Lucky what I understood is we are overriding style  portlet-borderless-bar for div id = p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_. Can you provide some CSS help on this front like how styles are applied to only specific element. I am not able to find this any where.

Comment: specific element means? what is ur req?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_ .portlet-borderless-bar {
display:none;
}

p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_ .portlet-topper {
display: none;
}

p_p_id_top_WAR_SecondPortletProjectportlet_ .portlet-title {
display: none;
}
```

As you are using **css class** you need to give **space** before using it.

More Info css [.class selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misread your question - You're explicitly asking about an embedded portlet. Disregard my answer, I'm not deleting it as this question might be found by others that are looking for this solution for non-embedded portlets.

---

I'm suggesting a slightly different approach than you ask for:

- Don't display portlet borders. This will do the job if you also uncheck the "Display Edit Controls" checkbox in the dockbar. However, it will allow you to move the portlets on the page, configure them as you need.
- Alternatively, specify in your theme that you don't want to show the borders by default - this way you don't have to change each single portlet's borders, but they're all gone at the same time (provided the current border-display-setting is on default):

  ```
    in liferay-look-and-feel.xml add this line:
    <setting configurable="true"
             key="portlet-setup-show-borders-default" 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="false" />
  ```
- When you disable borders, some handle will only appear if a) "Display Edit Controls" is checked AND the user is hovering the mouse over a portlet.
- After that, don't grant the full Administrator role to people that you don't want to see the controls at all. Instead create an alternative role with permissions that match your requirements - this typically involves setting portlet preferences for the single portlets, configuring permissions for them as well as changing/modifying pages (try them out, I can't name them from the top of my head)

Comment: Olaf If I want to achieve Like "non of the user(admin also)" to edit preferences/delete/minimize and maximize portlet I should be able to do it in role permission ?

Comment: I checked this in control panel and found we cannot remove/Add permission to Administrator role so I guess admin will see this control ? This is not what I want. Basically portlet is my top bar and I donot want to give an impression to Admin even that this is portlet.